# Porting APL*PLUS PC workspaces to Dyalog APL or GNU APL

Tags: apl, dyalog

I would like to use my old APL*PLUS PC functions on Dyalog or GNU APL. Is there a way to convert workspaces (preferred) or functions without having to retype the functions?

I have tried reformatting the functions as a character matrix in APL*PLUS PC (control A in the edit window) and saving in a .txt file.  But the characters are not translating correctly. The font used for APL*PLUS PC runs on DOS and does not load into Windows or Linux. The Dyalog fonts work fine in Notepad but they do not translate the characters from APL*PLUS PC correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you write the ⎕VR of each function to a native file using ⎕NAPPEND, I would expect that you can read this file into Dyalog APL with ⎕NREAD using data type 82, I would expect this to translate things correctly:

```
  filename ⎕NTIE ¯1
  source←⎕NREAD ¯1 82 ¯1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about APL*PLUS but IBM APL2 (and therefore also GNU APL) as well as Dyalog APL provide the )IN and )OUT commands that read and store an entire workspace in an interchange format (.atf files) that should be understood by the interpreters of different vendors. These commands should also take care of font conversions and the like.

Comment: They are `]in` and `]out` in Dyalog APL (i.e. with square brackets instead of round parentheses).